# How to get record fast when you have switchoffset in your where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a query where i have to get records from database with switchoffset in where clause and it taking hell of time. For example:

```
 CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
 ID int,
 Date datetime,
 Name char(20))
```

Just like below i have > 100k records in table (that was the real scenario). Below is just 10 records, result will come fast, but if we try this with 5000 records, it just stuck for minutes.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable( ID, Date, Name )
VALUES( 1, GETDATE(), 'abc' );

INSERT INTO #TempTable( ID, Date, Name )
VALUES( 2, GETDATE(), 'abc' );

INSERT INTO #TempTable( ID, Date, Name )
VALUES( 3, GETDATE(), 'abc' );

INSERT INTO #TempTable( ID, Date, Name )
VALUES( 4, GETDATE(), 'abc' );

INSERT INTO #TempTable( ID, Date, Name )
VALUES( 5, GETDATE(), 'abc' );

INSERT INTO #TempTable( ID, Date, Name )
VALUES( 6, GETDATE(), 'abc' );
INSERT INTO #TempTable( ID, Date, Name )
VALUES( 7, GETDATE(), 'abc' );
INSERT INTO #TempTable( ID, Date, Name )
VALUES( 8, GETDATE(), 'abc' );
INSERT INTO #TempTable( ID, Date, Name )
VALUES( 9, GETDATE(), 'abc' );
INSERT INTO #TempTable( ID, Date, Name )
VALUES( 10, GETDATE(), 'abc' );
SELECT *
FROM #TempTable
WHERE CAST(SWITCHOFFSET([Date], '-07:00') AS DATE) = '2019-11-20';
```

Using switchoffset in where condition taking hell of time, and i have to get the records as per the time offset. **Is there any way to get over this problem?**

Comment: *" there any way to get over this problem?"* Good indexing?

Comment: Anecdote: I have found temp tables are nice when storing a few rows but perform badly with many thousand rows. I guess it has to do with dynamic allocating disk/tempDB. Anyway, try to use a table variable instead

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to avoid function calls on columns.  So, try doing this in the reverse order:

```
SELECT *
FROM #TempTable
WHERE CAST(Date AS DATE) = SWITCHOFFSET('2019-11-20', '+07:00')
```

One exception is `CAST()`.  This still allows an index to be used.

Note:  You want an index on `(Date)` for performance.

Comment: i tried reverse order, still it takes too much time with switchoffset

Comment: @AnilThakur . . . Do you have an index on `(date)`.  That is what will really improve performance.